# Click effect on Relative Layout from listview row item

Tags: android, android-studio

I have listview in which i am adding items from a custom layout xml file. I want to apply click effect (background change of Parent Layout, i.e. The layout of custom xml file).

Comment: post your code it may be help .

Comment: do not use background color of items row  layout .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
            }
        });
```

in getView() method

Comment: Hi Yasoda,

I am using a  class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> { and in getview() of this i am adding item in a row...

Comment: in that getView() method find the view like View view = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout); then add above code.